# Missing Assembily Reference

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, xml-serialization, sgen

I have produced a custom class serializer for a sole class contained in 'VcdcClassStructure.dll' using [`sgen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk3w6240%28VS.80%29.aspx) as-per the documentation. The documents now state that all I need to do is

1. Add assembaly references to both 'VcdcClassStructure.dll' and the sgen-generated 'VcdcClassStructure.XmlSerializers.dll'.
2. Add references to the namespace that contains the newly generated serialization classes via

   using VcdcClassStructure;
   using Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly;`

(I have confirmed that the namespaces are correct using DotPeek).

I have then changed my code from

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(message));
serializer.Serialize(writer, vcdMsg);
```

to

```
messageSerializer serializer = new messageSerializer();
serializer.Serialize(writer, vcdMsg);
```

but on compilation I am getting

> The type or namespace name 'VcdcClassStructure' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

and

> The type or namespace name 'Xml' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I have reference the relevant assemblies and added the `using` code for the namespace. **Why is the compiler complaining about these references?**

Thanks for your time.

---

*Edit. To prove that I have not missed any of the steps above.*

[image]

Comment: Please toggle the "2 Warnings", so we can see them - I hope they will be revealing

Comment: Ah, damn. So sorry to waste your time. They were reviling. The DLLs generated are targeting a higher .NET framework than the application... Stupidity yet again by me. Thanks very much for your help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked, and the process described works correctly. I would have to assume, therefore, that you've made an error in the steps. It works fine (note: the type I created in the library was `SomeType`, hence the names):

[image]

You might want to try going through the steps again.

Comment: Mark, thanks for the reply. I have checked this thoroughly, and I can assure you that the steps described above are indeed what I have done. One complexity I thought un-relevant was that I am adding these references to a class library, but this should make no difference anyway. Again, thanks for your time.

Comment: I have added the same screen shot as yours to show I have not missed out anything. Do you have any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Note: it isn't clear in the screen, but my references there are all *file* references, not *project* references. In many ways, once you've built the custom serializer you want to **not build VcscClassStructure again** - I would recommend not even having it in the solution. Is this perhaps because you are using a project reference?

Comment: @Killercam in your error list, can you please tell me what the "2 Warnings" are? I have a sneaky suspicion it will be important.

Comment: I have put the errors in the initial question. They are Assembly Reference errors. My references are also file references, referencing the DLL used by sgen and the DLL generated by sgen...